# how to create login and create account page in same page in magento 2

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.1, customer-registration

How to create login and register page on the same page and below-attached screen short.

[image]

Comment: Please specify the magento version. Also, please share  what you have tried so far?

Comment: magento version 2.3.1

Comment: In the past, I have done it for Magento1 - https://blog.magepsycho.com/merging-registration-form-with-default-login-page-of-magento-creating-mini-registration-form/ Maybe this can be used as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Override customer_account_login.xml page in your theme

app/design/frontend/vendore/theme/Magento_Customer/layout folder

Update below code in your file.

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
        <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info1" as="form_additional_info1"/>
            </block>
             <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="attribute_data" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\AddressAttributeData</argument>
                </arguments>
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
        </container>

        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Set css based on your requirements.